# Conditional formatting on Pivot Table with no existing conditional formatting rules

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, conditional-formatting

I have a report (several actual) with Pivots that appear to have conditional formatting (each cycle week is color coded), but there are no rules for any part of the workbook. The reports contain some macros but none of the VBA references any type of formatting. When I add new data to the pivot source and refresh, the cycle week on the new rows in the pivot is formatted just like the previous data (implying there is conditional formatting on either the column or the pivot).

In summary: no conditional formatting under 'manage rules', nor any VBA that would format; how do I modify or remove this formatting without recreating the entire report?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out. In the Pivot table select a cell that contains the value you want to format. Then move the cursor left until a horizontal-arrow appears- click, and all like values will be selected, including rows with calculated values. Then right-click, "Format cells...", and choose your desired format (font, border, and/or fill). If you only want a single column formatted, then you can clear the formats from other columns where the formats are automatically applied.

Not technically "conditional" formatting, but it's practically the same as using a simple formula to format an entire column.